# Hide a menu (navigation bar) on all posts

Tags: menus, navigation

I would like to know if it is possible to hide the navigation bar on all posts.
Thanks so much.

Comment: Everything is possible.  However, there's no way anyone can tell you how to actually do this without A LOT more detail.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to hide the top bar menu then you can check it on wordpress.org they alreay provide the full solution.

you can put this in your custom css.
if you do not know where to add custom CSS then go to theme customization inside the appearance and you can easily access custom CSS.

@media (max-width: 768px) {
.top-bar-navigation {
display: none !important;
}
}

Comment: @Farad, how do you know what CSS selector to target?